# Dynamically updating grid in Vaadin application

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have an Vaadin application, which using Grid to show log messages from background thread. Is there a way to refresh Grid when I add element to log messages list? In the below example I use button to simulate log event.

**My UI class**

```
@SpringUI
@Push
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        //container
        VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(content);
        //grid
        Grid<LogEntry> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.addColumn(LogEntry::getDateTime);
        grid.addColumn(LogEntry::getMessage);
        grid.setDataProvider(DataProvider.ofCollection(logger.getEntries()));
        content.addComponent(grid);
        //button to simulate log event
        Button button = new Button("Log"); 
        button.addClickListener(e -> logger.log(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        content.addComponent(button);
    }
}
```

**My Logger class**

```
@SpringComponent
@VaadinSessionScope
public class Logger {
    private List<LogEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<LogEntry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void log(String message){
        LogEntry entry = new LogEntry(message);
        entries.add(entry);
    }
}
```

**My LogEntry class**

```
public class LogEntry {
    private final LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private final String message;

    public LogEntry(String message) {
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.message = message;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: The UI must somehow be notified, that there is new data.  E.g. a bus with pubsub or some sort of observer pattern. When updating the UI outside of the its scope, be sure to use UI.access

Comment: grid.addRow(new LogEntry(...))